# find files in folder from list and paste path

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using the following string to find files into folders, but I would like to make it search automatically from a list of names.
the actual code is:

```
    Sub Find_Files()
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
fldr.Show
f = fldr.SelectedItems(1)
f = f & "\"
NumRows = Range("B14", Range("B14").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
For i = 14 To NumRows
sn = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir """ & f & Active.Cells & """ /s /a /b").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)
Cells(i, 2).Offset(0, 1).Resize(UBound(sn) + 1) = Application.Transpose(sn)
Next i
ext:
End Sub
```

I've tried to change the old version which had "ibox" code into a "For i=14 to NumRows" loop, but it seems to not work.
do anyone has an advice on how to make it work?(I'm new with vba coding)

thanks in advance, 
Riccardo

Comment: Hi. welcome to SO. You get the best answers by showing your own effort to solve the problem, instead of just stating what you wnt to achieve...

Comment: Hi. welcome to SO. You get the best answers by showing your own effort to solve the problem, instead of just stating what you wnt to achieve... – JoSSte

Hi @JoSSte, thanks for your replay. I'm currently working on the code, but I have no clue on how to solve the problem. At the moment I'm trying with a classic For i to NumRows loop, but I can't go any further. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The code you have listed is with the ibox. have you got some (not working) code with the loop you described?

Comment: @JoSSte yes, here is the actual code:

Sub Find_Files()
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
fldr.Show
f = fldr.SelectedItems(1)
f = f & "\"
NumRows = Range("B14", Range("B14").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
For i = 14 To NumRows
sn = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir """ & f & Active.Cells & """ /s /a /b").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)
Cells(i, 2).Offset(0, 1).Resize(UBound(sn) + 1) = Application.Transpose(sn)
Next i
ext:
End Sub

it seems the loop doesn't works.

Comment: please update your queston ;-)

Comment: @JoSSte alright done. I'm new to both vba and this website so i'm a bit struggling. what do you think about this code? thanks mate!

Comment: which office application are you using btw? if you mouseover the vba tag, there are some recommendations...

Comment: excel 2016..sorry to bother you all but I'm trying to make it up for tonight

Comment: I'm just trying to help you get your question answered...

Comment: didn't meant to be rude, my point was "I haven't studied nor vba nor this website because I'm fresh new to both and have no time today to unfortunately". thanks for your kind help I do really appreciate what you are doing to help me. @JoSSte